# Проблема с вставкой изображения с помощью v-bind

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, изображения

Хочу сделать так, чтобы тег img c помощью v-bind вывел картинку, которая лежит в папке assets. Путь к изображению указан в свойстве объекта в модели, которая представляет собой массив из объектов. Данные передаются как надо, судя по просмотру кода страницы в браузере, но изображения нет.

Вид объекта:

```js
{id: 1, title: 'HTML5', rate: 4, image: '../assets/image 1.png'}
```

Тег:

```html
 <img class="skillImg" :src="elem.image" alt="">
```

[image: На странице изображение не отображается, хотя через просмотр кода видно, что данные передались.]

UPD: Добавляю вид структуры проекта. Выделен компонент, в котором все происходит.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется путь не правильный, попробуйте просто `./assets/image 1.png` и желательно избегать пробелов, ну и к вопросу не мешала бы структура проекта, но основная логика такая что ассеты лежат на том же уровне что index.html и поэтому `../` — лишнее, а `v-bind` не причем так как он делает свое дело (подстановку)

Comment: Все же, если я указываю именно этот путь руками в src, не используя v-bind, все работает как надо. Структуру приложения добавил к вопросу.

Comment: А если сбилдите тоже работает с двумя точками?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь подставить строку, а не путь до файла, сначала импортируйте файл и подставьте путь к нему

Вам необходимо "сказать" сборщику о том, что необходимо добавить файл в сборку, для этого явно импортируйте его, результат импорта будет являться путём к файлу.

```
<script setup>
import Image1 from '@/assets/image 1.png'
import Image2 from '@/assets/image 2.png'
import Image3 from '@/assets/image 3.png'
import Image4 from '@/assets/image 4.png'

const items = [
    { id: 1, title: 'HTML5', rate: 4, image: Image1 },
    { id: 2, title: 'HTML6', rate: 4, image: Image2 },
    { id: 3, title: 'HTML7', rate: 4, image: Image3 },
    { id: 4, title: 'HTML8', rate: 4, image: Image4 },
]
</script>

<template>
  <img v-for="item of items" :key="item.id" :src="item.image" />
</template>
```

Когда вы указываете `src` прямо в `template` для `img`, то сборщик автоматически обнаруживает и импортирует файл подставляя путь точно так же, как бы вы использовали пример выше